# `fundrawtransaction` error when trying to spend an HTLC

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, wallet, input-script

I'm trying to use the `fundrawtransaction` RPC command in order to create a transaction spending an HTLC output. Here is the command i've entered:

```
fundrawtransaction "02000000019ab30b02450c227d38d11f1e32de4139c4b14e6496e8c791615673be577691e10000000000fdffffff01a00f000000000000160014d095ce864aa19d47371c4a87c3c61a3cdd180b0b00000000" "{\"changeAddress\": \"bc1qccvnpr2rgfh4k7mcaty4dn3nesmtsyhwn5d58q\", \"outputs\": [{\"script\": \"6352210242625461fa5e6d69921fc95973b9ad4b139cbd16bbb4dd82a59c15f90193b25567a8f1e84f1a9abb1dce8d2a0b2a1e3cbb0c5fb41baf5f8220e14e7d059b463e3b88ac76a91402ec9dcf6c138a3d8c7ae214e2ce37577766f321388670a02211af0daf491b036b0eb4ded2861dbc7b21e11c8b010f70cc282f4e9e3fb81c752ae87\", \"amount\": 0}]}"
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Unexpected key outputs (code -3)
```

I don't understand what this error relates to.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a JSON key `outputs` in the second argument to `fundrawtransaction` (named "options"). This is not a recognized parameter.

It looks like you are trying to pass a redeemscript to the command for it to be able to create a valid scriptsig. You probably want to pass this script as part of the `solving_data` key inside the "options" parameter. See the documentation for `fundrawtransaction`.

Note `fundrawtransaction` only works for legacy script though. I see you are trying to pass an `amount` key as well, i assume it's for the Bitcoin Core wallet to sign the transaction using a Segwit signature hash. You should probably use PSBT commands in the Bitcoin Core wallet instead.